# Gauss theorem on a finite sheet

Tags: electric-field

I derived electric field at a distance z above and perpendicular to the centre of a sheet as
E = [image]

Now i want to approximate the sheet as a point charge and derive the electric field . I am not sure what am i suppose substitute in the equation

Can anyone explain the next step

Comment: l=w = small , z = large

Comment: If the given comment isn't enough use the next fact: Ratio arctan(X)/X approaches 1 when X approaches zero. Angle arctan(X) must be said as the number of radians. BTW your question doesn't show that you know what the written symbols mean. Hopefully you do not expect that someone deciphers the formula for you.